# how to get all items of listview with them positions and intent them to another activity and can go next and back position

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent, position

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = mAdapter.getItem(position).getName();
            String title = mAdapter.getItem(position).getTitle();
            String url = mAdapter.getItem(position).getUrl();
            String link = mAdapter.getItem(position).getLink();
            int lastPosition = mAdapter.getCount();
           /* for(int i = position;i < lastPosition;i++){
                 nextName = mAdapter.getItem(i).getName();
                 nextTitle = mAdapter.getItem(i).getTitle();
                 nextMusicLink = mAdapter.getItem(i).getLink();
                 nextImageUrl = mAdapter.getItem(i).getUrl();

            }*/
          int pos = (int) mAdapter.getItemId(position);


            int pos1  = mAdapter.getPosition(imageRecord);
            String nextName = mAdapter.getItem(position+1).getName();
            String nextTitle =mAdapter.getItem(position+1).getTitle();
            String nextMusicLink = mAdapter.getItem(position+1).getLink();
            String nextImageUrl = mAdapter.getItem(position+1).getUrl();


            Bundle extras  = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("name",nextName);
            extras.putString("title",nextTitle);
            extras.putParcelableArrayList("list",records);
           // extras.putParcelable("list",imageRecord);
            //extras.putLong("id",id+1);
            extras.putInt("position",position);
            extras.putString("url",nextImageUrl);
            extras.putString("link",nextMusicLink);
            linksModel1.setArtistName(name);
            linksModel1.setSongName(title);
            linksModel1.setImageUrl(url);
            linksModel1.setMusicLink(link);


            linksSharedPrefManager = new LinksSharedPrefManager(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
            linksSharedPrefManager.saveLInk(linksModel1);





            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), music_player.class);


            intent.putExtras(extras);



            startActivity(intent);




        }
    });
```

> this is my list view and i want to send next and back positions with values to another activity
>   to use next positions values you see i wnated to send positions +1

```
public class ImageRecord implements Serializable, Parcelable {
private String url;
private String title;
private String name;
private String duration;
private String link;

public ImageRecord(String url, String title, String name, String duration, String link) {
    this.url = url;
    this.title = title;
    this.name = name;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.link = link;
}

protected ImageRecord(Parcel in) {
    url = in.readString();
    title = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    duration = in.readString();
    link = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<ImageRecord> CREATOR = new Creator<ImageRecord>() {
    @Override
    public ImageRecord createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ImageRecord(in);
    }

    @Override
    public ImageRecord[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ImageRecord[size];
    }
};

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(url);
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeString(duration);
    parcel.writeString(link);
}
```

}

> this is my model class

```
public class ImageRecordsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageRecord> {
@Override
public int getPosition(@Nullable ImageRecord item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

private final ImageLoader mImageLoader;
ImageRecord imageRecords;
ArrayList<ImageRecord> imageRecordArrayList;

public ImageRecordsAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.special_list_item);

    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue(), new BitmapLruCache());
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.special_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // NOTE: You would normally use the ViewHolder pattern here
    NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2) ;
    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

    ImageRecord imageRecord = getItem(position);


    if (imageRecord != null) {
        imageView.setImageUrl(imageRecord.getUrl(), mImageLoader);
        textView.setText(imageRecord.getTitle());
        textView1.setText(imageRecord.getName());
        try {
            m.setDataSource(imageRecord.getLink());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    return convertView;
}

public void swapImageRecords(List<ImageRecord> objects) {
    clear();

    for (ImageRecord object : objects) {
        add(object);
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

> this is my adapter

```
 /*  nextUrl = (String)intent.getSerializableExtra("url");
    nextName = (String)intent.getSerializableExtra("name");
    nextTitle = (String)intent.getSerializableExtra("title");
    nextLink = (String)intent.getSerializableExtra("link");*/
    records = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
    positionNext =Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("position").toString());
   // imageRecord = (ImageRecord)intent.getParcelableExtra("list");
   // id = (int)intent.getLongExtra("id",1);
```

> i used to get that intents here

```
  next_btn_music_player.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            nextLink = records.get(positionNext).getLink();
            nextName = records.get(positionNext).getName();
            nextTitle = records.get(positionNext).getTitle();
            nextUrl = records.get(positionNext).getUrl();

            linksModel1.setArtistName(nextName);
            linksModel1.setSongName(nextTitle);
            linksModel1.setImageUrl(nextUrl);
            linksModel1.setMusicLink(nextLink);

            linksSharedPrefManager = new LinksSharedPrefManager(Objects.requireNonNull(context));
            linksSharedPrefManager.saveLInk(linksModel1);
            try {
                backgroundAudioService.next();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           /* try {
                backgroundAudioService.next();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/


            Intent intent1 = new Intent(music_player.this , music_player.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });


}
```

> and use next button to send next positions values to next activity

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Assuming that the number of items in the list is more than a handful, you definitely **do not** want to put the entire list of items in an `Intent` as an "extra". The size of an `Intent` is limited and passing huge amounts of data like this will not work. You are better off keeping the list of items in a `static` variable that can be accessed directly by all of your code. Or put the list of items in a database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/769265/david-wasser
and how can i make my listview items static?

Comment: i want to get next items of item selected

Comment: In your `Activity` when you create the `Adapter` you pass it the list of items. Put that in a `public static` variable. All classes can access it then by using `Classname.variablename` and you don't need to pass it around.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand your problem. What isn't working as you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Try it for +1 position data.

`int po= position+1; 
 String nextName = mAdapter.getItem(po).getName();`